# Fill triangle PGF

Tags: tikz-pgf

first problem I need help with.

I defined a few coordinates, some of them are connected. Some were defined by intersection etc. 
Now, i want to fill the triangle stretched out by coordinates D-E-G. It does not work. Is there anything missing in my code? I tried a lot of different things. The one given below is just a example.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
   xlabel={X-Achse},
   ylabel={Y-Achse},
   xmin=0,xmax=100,
   ymin=0,ymax=200,
   xtickmin=0,xtickmax=100,
   ytickmin=0,ytickmax=200,
   height=9cm,width=9cm,
   title={Überschrift},
   ]

%define coordinates   
\coordinate[fill, circle, inner sep = 2pt,label=below:$A$] (A) at (40,40) {};
\coordinate[fill, circle, inner sep = 2pt,label=above:$B$] (B) at (20,80) {};
\coordinate[fill, circle, inner sep = 2pt,label=above:$C$] (C) at (60,160) {};
\coordinate[fill, circle, inner sep = 2pt,label=right:$D$] (D) at (80,80) {};

%draw lines
\draw [thick,dashed](A) -- (B) 
    node[below,sloped,midway] {$wurscht$} ;
\draw [thick,dashed,red](A) -- (C) 
    node[above,sloped,midway] {$egal$} ;
\draw [thick,green](C) -- (D) 
    node[above,sloped,midway] {$wayne$} ;

%intersections,     
\coordinate[fill, circle, inner sep = 2pt,label=left:$E$] (E) at 
    (intersection of A--C and B--D);
\coordinate[fill, circle, inner sep = 2pt,label=right:$F$] (F) at ($(A)!0.7!(C)$);
\coordinate[fill, circle, inner sep = 2pt,label=right:$G$,] (G) at ($(A)!1.5cm!-90:(E)$);

%filling D-E-G
\draw [fill=red](E) -- (G) -- (D) -- (E) -- cycle;

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Use `\draw[fill=red] (E.center) -- (G.center) -- (D.center) -- cycle;`

Comment: merci, thx a lot. Haven't found this topic in forum yet. Sorry, for duplicating.